# Hi, how do I run a report that shows me all the people that became a NEW member (not renewals) for the month of October 2019?

Tags: civimember

how do I run a report that shows me all the people that became a NEW member (not renewals) for the month of October 2019?

Answer (score 2):

If you use Adv Search and set the Date range for example to be 'Join Date' in October does that not give what you need?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SE. It depends on how you have used membership status, but in the Membership Details reports, if you go to the filters tab, you may be able to just filter on the new status for recent memberships or perhaps better filter on the membership since field with an appropriate date range. Have a play to see what works best for you.